# A Google Map API trouble,ask for support

Tags: html, google-maps

I wrote a piece of code with Google Map to realize the location and GPS function.
But the navigation route always can't shows,I don't konw where is wrong?
Ask for help.Who can help me?
Thank you!

javascript code

```
<script type="text/javascript">  

$( "#map-page" ).live( "pageinit", function() {  

    var directionsDisplay;  
    var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();  
    var map;  
    var salon = new google.maps.LatLng(22.981666,120.194301);  
    var defaultLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(22.983587,120.22599);  // Default to Hollywood, CA when no geolocation support  

    if ( navigator.geolocation ) {  
        function success(pos) {  
            // Location found, show map with these coordinates  
            drawMap(new google.maps.LatLng(pos.coords.latitude, pos.coords.longitude));  
            calcRoute(new google.maps.LatLng(pos.coords.latitude, pos.coords.longitude));      
        }  

        function fail(error) {  
            console.log(error);  
            drawMap(defaultLatLng);  // Failed to find location, show default map  
        }  

        // Find the users current position.  Cache the location for 5 minutes, timeout after 6 seconds  
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, fail, {maximumAge: 500000, enableHighAccuracy:true, timeout: 6000});  
    } else {  
        drawMap(defaultLatLng);  // No geolocation support, show default map      
    }  

    function drawMap(latlng) {  

        directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();  

        var myOptions = {  
            zoom: 10,  
            center: latlng,  
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP  

        };  

        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), myOptions);  
        directionsDisplay.setMap(map);  
        // Add an overlay to the map of current lat/lng  

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({  
            position: latlng,  
            map: map,  
            title: "Greetings!"  
        });  

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({  
            position:new google.maps.LatLng(22.981666,120.194301),  
            map:map,  
            title:"the salon"  
        });  
    }  

    function calcRoute(latlng) {  
    var start = latlng;  
    var end = new google.maps.LatLng(22.981666,120.194301);  
    var request = {  
        origin:start,  
        destination:end,  
        travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING  
    };  
    directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {  
        if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {  
        directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);  
    }  
  });  
}  


});  


    </script>
```

Comment: I hope you have `sensor=true` ?

Comment: Note about your code -- Your comment reads -- "Find the users current position.  Cache the location for 5 minutes, timeout after 6 seconds" -- BUT your code reads: navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, fail, {maximumAge: 500000, enableHighAccuracy:true, timeout: 6000});   There are two issues.  500000 is 8.33 minutes, not 5 minutes (500000/1000/60).  BUT, more importantly, that's now what maximumAge means.  You are telling the device the location age you are willing to accept, but telling it how long to cache it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have worked out
this piece of code is wrong

```
    if ( navigator.geolocation ) {    
    function success(pos) {    
        // Location found, show map with these coordinates    
        drawMap(new google.maps.LatLng(pos.coords.latitude, pos.coords.longitude));    
        calcRoute(new google.maps.LatLng(pos.coords.latitude, pos.coords.longitude));        
    }    

    function fail(error) {    
        console.log(error);    
        drawMap(defaultLatLng);  // Failed to find location, show default map    
    }    

    // Find the users current position.  Cache the location for 5 minutes, timeout after 6 seconds    
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, fail, {maximumAge: 500000, enableHighAccuracy:true, timeout: 6000});    
} else {    
    drawMap(defaultLatLng);  // No geolocation support, show default map        
}
```

i direct

```
// Location found, show map with these coordinates    
drawMap(defaultLatLng);  
calcRoute(defaultLatLng);
```